# Singleton Method Gives Error in OnResum (Android)

Tags: android, fragment, global-variables, onresume

I have a problem that I could not understand why it is happening.

I have a fragment, and in the fragment I have the on resume method as below:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    System.out.println("number 1");

    int s = ((StarterApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication()).getRefreshNotificationVar();

    System.out.println("number 2");
    s = s + 1;

    System.out.println("number 3");
    ((StarterApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication()).setRefreshNotificationVar(s);

    System.out.println("number 4");
    System.out.println(s);


}
```

And my singletons are as below:

```
private int refreshNotificationVar;

public int getRefreshNotificationVar() {

    System.out.println("check out here");
    return refreshNotificationVar;
}

public void setRefreshNotificationVar(int refreshNotificationVar) {
    this.refreshNotificationVar = refreshNotificationVar;
    System.out.println(refreshNotificationVar+" is my number");

}
```

And I call this fragment once in the oncreate of the activity as below, which works fine. The singleton methods and else.

```
newsFeedFragment fragment2 = new newsFeedFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction2.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "news_feed_fragment");
fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```

And I call this fragment again with a button as below. However here I start to get the error when the singleton method starts.

```
newsFeedFragment fragment = new newsFeedFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container));
fragmentTransaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("notifications_fragment"));
fragmentTransaction.show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("news_feed_fragment"));
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragment.onResume();
```

When the fragment loads for the first time, it works fine, but when I show the fragment and start the onResume method manually, I start to get the error as below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.my_last.mylast.newsFeedFragment.onResume(newsFeedFragment.java:223)
    at com.my_last.mylast.MainActivity.go_to_main_view(MainActivity.java:565)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: What's in newsFeedFragment.java on line 223? On this line you have NullPointerException

Comment: Is `this.getActivity()` returning `null`?

Comment: Yes the line is `int s = ((StarterApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication()).getRefreshNotificationVar();`

Comment: But when the fragment is created for the first time, it is not giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("number 1");
        int s = ((MainApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication()).getRefreshNotificationVar();
        System.out.println("number 2");
        s = s + 1;
        System.out.println("number 3");
        ((MainApplication) this.getActivity().getApplication()).setRefreshNotificationVar(s);
        System.out.println("number 4");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Looks Like Activity Instance is null . Instead of onresume do the same operation on onActivityCreated Method . Please refer the above code.

Comment: Hello Naveen, as I am calling the onResume from the activity while showing the fragment, isn't there another way, I do not want to call the onCreate method as it will load the whole fragment from the beginning. Why am I getting the error in the on resume? It is not giving any errors when the fragment is loaded for the first time. The onResume method is processes successfully while fragment creation, but while calling onResume after that I get the error.